# Parse json using php

Tags: php, json

This is my json

```
{
  "product": [
    {
      "styles": [
        {
          "price": "$65.00"
        },
        {
          "price": "$65.00"
        }
      ],
      "productId": "444",

    }
  ],
  "statusCode": "200"
}
```

I am trying to get the all the price.. I tried the below code but couldn't get the results

```
$obj = json_decode($response);
foreach($obj['product']['styles'] as $chunk) {
echo $chunk['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access decoded data as an associative array, you should pass `true` as the second parameter of the [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode) function:

```
foreach($obj['product'] as $products) {
    foreach ($products['styles'] as $style) {
        echo $style['price'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I get  Undefined index: styles and Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: This answer is correct - but also the supplied JSON isn't valid. The comma after "productId": "444" should be removed

Comment: @Naren I've updated the answer to match exectly your json schema.

Answer (score 1):

You've got nested arrays. product contains an array objects, so you'd actually need

```
$obj = json_decode($response);
echo $obj->product[0]->productID; // 44
                  ^^^---
echo $obj->product[0]->styles[1]->price; // second $65.00
```